# Is there any way to completely hide Web Application code?

Tags: java, html, browser, embed

HTML5 code can easily be seen through "Inspect Element," or retrieved from "sources."

I am wondering if there is any way at all to hide a Web application's code completely on the client side from the browser.

All languages are welcome, so embedding applications (such as Java Applets) are acceptable. Are there any clever ways to approach this problem?

Comment: Back-end code yes. Front-end code no. However, there are ways to make the front end code harder to understand (minify, obfuscate, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Vaadin

Using a server-side oriented web app framework such as [*Vaadin*](http://www.Vaadin.com/) where your business logic lives only on the server written entirely in Java while the framework automatically generates the HTML, CSS, JavaScript, DOM, AJAX, and WebSocket code necessary for presentation within the web browser gives you much masking of your critical code.

Any user will be able to see the auto-generated HTML and JavaScript and such, but it won't mean much.

The hacker will be able to manipulate that client-side code but it won't do much. For example a hacker could alter the HTML/JavaScript defining the values in a pop-up menu to add another unintended item. But your Java code on the server can check for unexpected values and handle the fault or throw an Exception.

And Vaadin performs integrity tests to verify that the client and server remain "in sync". Hacking the client-side code is likely to rapidly throw them out of sync.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to hide frontend code completely, because the user's browser must be able to read the code to execute it. This issue isn't limited to the web. Even native binaries can be inspected with a [disassembler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disassembler) - again, the user's CPU must be able to interpret the code, so a sufficiently skilled attacker could interpret it as well.

That said, obfuscating code can make it more difficult to read. JavaScript is often minified before it's put in production - primarily for performance reasons. This also offers a basic level of obscuring the functionality, protecting against less-skilled or less-motivated attackers. [Google's list of minifiy resources](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/MinifyResources) may be a good place to start.